# Simple Java + React app deployment causing high costs on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We developed an app with a React frontend, Java/Spring Boot backend and a Google hosted PostgreSQL database. The app has a company SSO and every user can post project experiences via form. These are saved in the database. So very simple.

The app is still in the staging phase so there are no visitors and it's generally not taking up much ressources. But the hosting costs are exorbitant. We were billed around 400€ for one month.

These are the app.yaml backend config:

> ```
> runtime: java17
> instance_class: F2
> inbound_services:
>   - warmup
> automatic_scaling:
>   min_idle_instances: 2
> ```

and the frontend config:

> ```
> runtime: nodejs18
>
> instance_class: F2
> automatic_scaling:
>   max_instances: 2
>   min_instances: 0
>   min_idle_instances: 0
>   max_idle_instances: 1
>
> service: frontend
>
> handlers:
>
> # Serve all static files with url ending with a file extension
>
> - url: /(.*\..+)$
>
>   static_files: build/\1
>
>   upload: build/(.*\..+)$
>
> # Catch all handler to index.html
>
> - url: /.*
>
>   static_files: build/index.html
>
>   upload: build/index.html
> ```

As you can see I kept 2 instances in idle otherwise App Engine goes to sleep after a couple of minutes and the app loading time would be very slow. Initially I thought this might be a problem and switch the backend to this config which didn't change anything:

> ```
> runtime: java17
> instance_class: F2
> automatic_scaling:
>   max_instances: 2
>   min_instances: 0
>   min_idle_instances: 0
>   max_idle_instances: 1
> ```

What am I doing wrong here? Is is the app.yaml config or the code or should I use something different than App Engine? We need to stay on Google Cloud in any case.

These are the costs broken down to the different services for this month:

[image]

Comment: Your biggest expense is the Certificate Authority Service. You need to find out if it's really needed or how you can reduce costs there. You're also using F2 instances which is double the price of F1 and you have a total of 3 of them which are always on. You can also tweak that to get your cost down - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing

Comment: @NoCommandLine afaik CAS is needed to enrypt traffic between the database which is one of the core features of App Engine. I already tried disabling it. The app won't work anymore which seems to make CAS an essential API. Also tried setting F2 to F1 already the app won't work anymore too which I don't understand. Maybe the CPU and memory power is not enough then? I don't know. One of my colleagues now pointed out that this is an enterprise account. Eg the certificates for CAS are 10x more expensive then for the "DevOps" package. I think the enterprise rates are a big problem. Thank you anyway!

Comment: ahh, the higher rates for Enterprise seems to explain the cost then (that CAS is your biggest expense). F1 not working is usually due to memory being exceeded which triggers a restart of the instance before it can fully load your App. It should show up in your logs. You can use App tracing to see where (if any) bottleneck exists.